# htaccess rewrite download link

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have try rewrite url like this link but show file not found

```
http://storage1.demo.com/download/2014/11/17/abc.zip?h=2de27c3e4b2cba560caca80f6e07ab2a&t=1416244533
```

this is my htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^download/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-\.]+)\.zip?h=(.*)&t=([0-9]+) index.php?type=get&y=$1&m=$2&d=$3&packagename=$4&h=$5&t=$6 [NC,L]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} h=(.*)&t=([0-9]+)
RewriteRule download/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]+)\.zip$ index.php?type=get&y=$1&m=$2&d=$3&packagename=$4&h=%1&t=%2 [NC,L]
```

With \- in [ ] !

Comment: Are you sure that the error did not come from `index.php` program ?

Comment: And you correctly send the (dot) `.htaccess` in text mode, with your ftp software...

Comment: yes,I checked .htaccess file name, this is error because not redirect to index.php

Comment: i founded a problem is apache,and your code working perfect ,Thanks